# Account Billing Address fields are coming Null in Flow

Tags: lightning, process-builder, visual-workflow

I am trying to populate Billing address from Person Account to one custom text fields on Event. Same flow is working fine when populating Billing address and Shipping Address from business account on Event. 
I have added isPerson account check as well. Also fields are queried in fetch record. Can anyone tell me what could be an issue?

Comment: I think for a person account, the address is compounded in `PersonMailingAddress` field and there are separate fields like `PersonMailingStreet` and `PersonMailingCity` to get values from.

Comment: Cant we use other address fields like billing address fields?